# Git Extensions Does Not Recognize Github RSA Signature

Tags: windows, git, github, git-extensions

When trying to clone a repository through the newest version of Git Extensions a window appears which states:

> The server's host key is not cached in the registry. You
>   have no guarantee that the server is the computer you
>   think it is.

Normally when using the command version of SSH you can add this footprint to the list of approved hosts, but using the front-end it doesn't work as expected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The front-end does not support any interactive prompts with the ssh (or git) command line process. Since I was using PuTTY I did the following to actually add this RSA signature to my approved hosts list:

`cd C:\Program Files (x86)\GitExtensions\PuTTY`

```
plink -agent github.com
```

Once the interactive prompt appears type 'y' to add it to the cache. You should be able to clone repositories from GitExtensions now using the "Github" feature.